# SOAP XML Tag differences

Tags: xml, soap

I have a newbie SOAP question. I've used REST a lot but not a lot of SOAP experience.

I'm trying to understand the various tags I'm seeing for the service I"m trying to access specifically the prefix for say envelope and body tags

I see

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
<soapenv:Body>

<s:Envelope>
<s:Body>

<soap:Envelope>
<soap:Body>

<soap-env:Envelope>
<soap-env:Body>
```

From the service I'm trying to access (Marketing Cloud) the documentation references various tags `<soap-ENV:Body>`, `<s:Envelope>`, etc.  After trying to get successful response using "Retrieve" Soapaction finally worked by using "`<s:Envelope>`", "`<s:Body>`, etc.

Is the difference between the tags version 1.2 and another version?

I think if I better understand the tags should help understand how to properly submit to the Marketing Cloud service using tools such as Postman.

Here are some examples and just not sure how to get these various ones working in Postman

**Example 1**

```
   <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <CreateRequest xmlns="http://exacttarget.com/wsdl/partnerAPI">
            <Options>
                <SaveOptions>
                    <SaveOption>
                        <PropertyName>*</PropertyName>
                        <SaveAction>UpdateAdd</SaveAction>
                    </SaveOption>
                </SaveOptions>
            </Options>
            <Objects xsi:type="Subscriber">
                <ObjectID xsi:nil="true">
                </ObjectID>
                <EmailAddress>help@example.com</EmailAddress>
                <Lists>
                    <ID>123</ID>
                    <ObjectID xsi:nil="true">
                    </ObjectID>
                </Lists>
            </Objects>
        </CreateRequest>
    </s:Body>
```

**Example 2**

```
 <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:UpdateRequest>
         <ns1:Options/>
         <ns1:Objects xsi:type="ns1:Subscriber">
            <ns1:Attributes>
               <ns1:Name>First Name</ns1:Name>
               <ns1:Value>Updated</ns1:Value>
            </ns1:Attributes>
            <ns1:Attributes>
               <ns1:Name>Last Name</ns1:Name>
               <ns1:Value>ViaAPI</ns1:Value>
            </ns1:Attributes>
            <ns1:SubscriberKey>012345</ns1:SubscriberKey>
            <ns1:Lists>
               <ns1:ID>12345</ns1:ID>
            </ns1:Lists>
            <ns1:Lists>
               <ns1:ID>12346</ns1:ID>
            </ns1:Lists>
         </ns1:Objects>
      </ns1:UpdateRequest>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
```